# Inserir icone em uma tabela

Tags: vue.js, tabela-html

tenho o seguinte código em um arquivo .vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="col-6">   
    <ModalRegister/>
    <div class="col-12">
      <b-table hover :items="rowData"></b-table>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ModalRegisterfrom './ModalRegister';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        rowData: [
          {nome: 'fts-001', modelo: "modelinho1", opção: "<i class='far fa-edit'></i>"}, 
          {nome: 'fts-002', modelo: "modelinho2", opção: "<i class='far fa-edit'></i>"}, 
          {nome: 'fts-003', modelo: "modelinho3", opção: "<i class='far fa-edit'></i>"}, 
          {nome: 'fts-004', modelo: "modelinho4", opção: "<i class='far fa-edit'></i>"}, 
        ],
      }
    },
    components: {
      ModalRegister
    }
  }
</script>
```

Mas ele não funciona, ele interpreta o código como texto e não coloca o icone. Como posso fazer para adicionar um ícone a tabela?

Comment: Como a sua pergunta esta incompleta, a solução genérica é a diretiva [`v-html`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html)([#docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)). Porém nada disso importa se não conhecermos o código fonte do componente `<b-table>`. Você poderia mostrar o código deste componente ou [edit] a pergunta para adicionar uma tag com a biblioteca que você está usando?

Answer (score 1):

Passa um campo **`fields`** no ***data*** e nele insere uma **`chave`** e um **`label`**, e no ***Html*** cria um **slot** dentro do `b-table` com a tag **i** pegando os valores do data:

```
<template>
  <div class="col-6">   
    <ModalRegister/>
    <div class="col-12">
      <b-table hover :fields="fields" :items="rowData">
        <template slot="opcao" slot-scope="{ item: { opcao} }">
          <i :class="'far ' + opcao"></i>
        </template>
      </b-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ModalRegisterfrom './ModalRegister';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fields: ['nome', 'modelo', { key: 'opcao', label: 'opção' }],
      rowData: [
        {nome: 'fts-001', modelo: "modelinho1", opcao: "<i class='fa-edit'></i>"}, 
        {nome: 'fts-002', modelo: "modelinho2", opcao: "<i class='fa-edit'></i>"}, 
        {nome: 'fts-003', modelo: "modelinho3", opcao: "<i class='fa-edit'></i>"}, 
        {nome: 'fts-004', modelo: "modelinho4", opcao: "<i class='fa-edit'></i>"}, 
      ],
    }
  },
  components: {
    ModalRegister
  }
}
</script>
```

> Também troque o nome do campo **opção** por **opcao**, pois, isto pode ocasionar erros no Javascript.

Comment: isso não resolveu... continuou com exatamente o mesmo problema

Comment: Estranho, aqui funcionou perfeitamente: https://codepen.io/leandrobeandrade/pen/KKPYVNB

Comment: estranho. mesmo copiando e colando seu codigo, aqui nao vai..